# Keep track of linux terminal commands in git

Tags: linux, git, linux-terminal

Is there a way we can keep track of commands executed in linux terminal in git? 
I would like to commit each command entered.

Comment: If you can execute a script on logout from the terminal, you should be able to backup the ~./bash_history file.

Comment: Another alternative would be to leverage off http://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server and deposit it in GIT rather then logger, or use something to read the log file after its written.

Comment: @davidgo I can log command history in several other ways but I am just curious to make it work with git properly. It should commit without logout script.